# Angular http request in ngif

Tags: angular

I have a table of data and one column has a button in it that opens a dialog popup based on the object from that row. I am trying to show/hide the button based on a http request that has to be called once per button to determine if the button should show/hide for that row. I set up a network call like this:

```
setupApi() {
  return this.http.get(url);
}

   shouldShowButton() {
      this.service.getJson()
        .subscribe(data => {
          return true;
        }, error => {
          return false;
        });
    }
```

And then on my button I have this:

```
<button mat-raised-button *ngIf="shouldShowButton() |  async"></button>
```

I am getting error on the ng-if saying my function returns void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure this a bit, and handle all request in the TS before displaying.

Reading your comments, we can gather....

If you have an unknown amount of items, you can use `forkJoin` to perform all requests in parallel based on the original array, then add the value to your original array that you are looping in your table in template. I would add a boolean prop in your array, where we determine that should the button be shown or not, here called `showBtn`

So Let's say your data looks like (after adding the bool prop):

```ts
myDat = [
  { name: "name1", showBtn: false },
  { name: "name2", showBtn: false },
  { name: "name3", showBtn: false },
  { name: "name4", showBtn: false }
];
```

Use array `map` to push requests to a helper array, which we then use `forkJoin` on, then add the boolean value to your original array:

```ts
shouldShowButton() {
  let reqs = [];
  this.myDat.map(btn => reqs.push(this.myService.getJson(btn.name)));

  this.myData = forkJoin(...reqs).pipe(
    map(val => {
      return val.map((curr, i, arr)=> {
        return {... this.myDat[i], showBtn: curr}
      })
    })
  )
}
```

now you have all data you need inside the observable `myData`, which you can use in the template like:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of myData | async">
  <td>
    {{item.name}}
  </td>
  <td>
    <button *ngIf="item.showBtn" (click)="doSomething(item)">Button!</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4msevw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

The async pipe expects an Observable. I would recommend using a variable instead of a function (to keep it simple and because running functions in your template is 'bad practice') like:

```
public showButton: boolean;

ngOnIinit() {
  this.shouldShowButton();
}

shouldShowButton() {
  this.service.getJson().subscribe(data => {
              this.showButton = true;
            }, error => {
              this.showButton = false;
            });
 }



 <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="this.showButton"></button>
```

For an 'unknown amount of buttons' you could use an object.

```
public showButtons: any = {};

ngOnIinit() {
      this.shouldShowButton('button1');
      this.shouldShowButton('button2');
      this.shouldShowButton('button2');
      ....
    }

    shouldShowButton(buttonName: string) {
      this.service.getJson(buttonName).subscribe(data => {
                  this.showButtons[buttonName] = true;
                }, error => {
                  this.showButtons[buttonName] = false;
                });
     }


<button mat-raised-button *ngIf="this.showButtons['button1']"></button>
<button mat-raised-button *ngIf="this.showButtons['button2']"></button>
<button mat-raised-button *ngIf="this.showButtons['button3']"></button>
```

Comment: the problem is I have an unknown number of buttons and each one needs to be checked so I would need n number of variables to capture which to turn each one on or off.

Comment: @Nick see my edit. Maybe something like that could be usable for your situation?

Comment: I can not call `this.shouldShowButton('button1');` in OnInit because I don't know how many buttons I will have so I can't call it a bunch of times in there.  I know this isn't the best way of doing it but it is the best we have at the moment until our API gets updated so I think we still need to go down the right of calling it each time in `*ngif`

Answer (score 0):

An `*ngIf` with the `async` pipe is expecting an Observable. You give a Subscription instead.

- remove your subcription in your `.ts`
- or do as @Bert Maurau suggests

Comment: In your first suggestion, you should mention that the method must return the observable.

Comment: @ConnorsFan You're right. Normally, when you remove the `.subscribe(...)`, you have an Observable ;)

Comment: Yes, but the method should return it. Just removing `.subscribe(...)` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

async pipe doesn't work like that, also your approach to show hide a button is not correct as there might several thousands of rows in the table and calling an api this many time is not good for the application performance.

You can try below:

1. Use Variable based *ngIf.
2. You can also include a flag in your table data to show/hide the button
3. Or remove async pipe it may work fine.