# Refresh Element After Loading and receiving Server Response

Tags: angular

This element should be updated after server response `div(*ngIf='IAmThatElement | async')`

Component

```
public IAmThatElement: boolean = false;

constructor(private returnAliveService: ReturnAliveService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.calledWhenPageLoaded
}

//Not sure why there is a get. If the element is linked, should updating it not get reflected on view
get calledWhenPageLoaded() {
    this.returnAliveService.getServerHealth()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.IAmThatElement = data.resut;
        }, error => {
            this.IAmThatElement = false;
        });

    return this.IAmThatElement;
}
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class ReturnAliveService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getServerHealth() : Observable<Data> {
        return this.http.get<Data>('URL');
    }
}
```

How should I update `IAmThatElement`. Newbie to `Angular`. Found something similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/58652468 still its not working for me. Help much appreciated

**---- Updated** with `Observable`. Not sure this is working and no idea how to show the boolean value in view after update

```
public IAmThatElement: Observable<boolean> = new Observable<boolean>();

constructor(private returnAliveService: ReturnAliveService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.returnAliveService.getServerHealth()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                //No idea on how to populate IAmThatElement with data and display content on view
                this.IAmThatElement = Observable.create(true);
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to take into account in your code:

1.- I don't know why there's a `get` before `calledWhenPageLoaded` method. I'd remove it.

2.- This is the important one: You have declared `IAmThatElement` as boolean in your component, but when binding it in the template, you are using `async` pipe, which means you are subscribing to an observable and this is not true. So you have two options:

- remove the `| async` pipe from the template.
- declare `IAmThatElement` as an observable (a BehaviourSubject for example) and change its value in the `calledWhenPageLoaded` method.

Note also that returning `IAmThatElement` in the `calledWhenPageLoaded` method has not effect.

For example:

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

public IAmThatElement: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

constructor(private returnAliveService: ReturnAliveService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.returnAliveService.getServerHealth()
        .subscribe(
            data => {                 
            this.IAmThatElement.next(data.result); // I suppose `data.result` is a true value here
        }, error => {
            this.IAmThatElement.next(false);
        });
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: I have update the code. There are two places I am stuck. Writing to `Observable` and displaying data from `Observable`

Comment: I added an example using a `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: The above code works only when ` IAmThatElement | async` is added back. Otherwise it does not refresh. My understanding, `IAmThatElement` is not subscribed. By adding `| async`, subscribing is enforced. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, of course, as I told in my post the `async` pipe is used to subscribe to observables. You changed your code to use an Observable, so you need to use the `async` pipe.